# Execute dynamic sql query output?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Platform: SQL Server 2016

I've written a SQL statement that outputs a series of SQL commands and I want to execute the output of this query in the same script. This is the query that builds the commands I want to execute.

```
select 
    'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER SYSNET.' + name + ';' 
from 
    sys.tables  
where  
    schema_name(schema_id) = 'sysnet' 
order by 
    1;
```

I know I need to capture the output in a variable and then execute it. I'm sure it's simple but everything I've tried didn't work and Google has failed me.

==================================================

Thanks for the answers!  scsimon technically gave the best answer since it provided the means of executing the output of any dynamic SQL and that's what I asked for. With that said, Ross Bush provided the simplest way for me to accomplish this specific task of transferring schema ownerships. In the end I used this...

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER ?;' 
  ,@whereand='AND schema_name(schema_id) = ''sysnet'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through those seems to be what you want.

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as RN, 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER SYSNET.'+ name + ';' as CMD 
into #mytemp
from sys.tables  where  
schema_name(schema_id)  = 'sysnet' 


declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @i int = 1
while @i <= (select max(RN) from #mytemp)
begin
    select @sql = CMD from #mytemp where RN = @i
    print @sql
    --exec(@sql)
    set @i = @i + 1
end

drop table #mytemp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best advice as the function below is an undocumented SQL Server function and may not be around in the future. That being said, I would use the `sp_MSforeachtable` table to issue a command for each table in the target database.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ?'
```